# Storing String Indexed Binary Data in File Using C#

Tags: c#, database, file, binary

I wonder what is the best way to store binary data indexed by a string key into a single file.

This would be the circumstances I would be looking for:

- Data indexed by a string key with variable length (max. 255 characters, ASCII only is fine).
- Binary data has variable length (500 bytes up to 10 KB).
- Amount of data stored < 5,000 entries.
- In production only functions "GetDataByKey" & "GetAllKeys" needed and therefore should be fast.
- Adding data is not used in production and can therefore be slow.

Is there any simple C# based library that would fit to those requirements?

I was looking at some NoSQL databases, but this seems to be a bit over the top for such a very simple data structure.

As only a small percentage of the data records are used during an application run I would prefer not to just read everything into memory on application start (e. g. using serialization), but instead just read the entries from the file that are really needed during runtime.

Any ideas or tips would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there seems not to be a solution/library available for this yet (probably, because the problem is just too simple to share it ;-) ), I've build a small class myself.

In case somebody else needs the same, that's the way I store this string key based binary data now:

```
internal class BinaryKeyStorage
{
    private const string FILE_PATH = @"data.bin";

    private static MemoryMappedFile _memoryFile;
    private static MemoryMappedViewStream _memoryFileStream;
    private static Dictionary<string, Entry> _index;

    private class Entry
    {
        public Entry(int position, int length)
        {
            Position = position;
            Length = length;
        }

        public int Position { get; }
        public int Length { get; }
    }

    public static void CreateFile(Dictionary<string, byte[]> keyValues)
    {
        // 4 bytes for int count of entries
        // and per entry:
        // - string length + 1 byte for string prefix
        // - 2x4 bytes for int address start and length
        var headerLength = 4 + keyValues.Keys.Sum(dataKey => dataKey.Length + 9);

        var nextStartPosition = headerLength;
        using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(FILE_PATH, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            binaryWriter.Write(keyValues.Count);

            // writing header
            foreach (var keyValue in keyValues)
            {
                binaryWriter.Write(keyValue.Key);
                binaryWriter.Write(nextStartPosition);
                binaryWriter.Write(keyValue.Value.Length);

                nextStartPosition += keyValue.Value.Length;
            }

            // writing data
            foreach (var keyValue in keyValues)
            {
                binaryWriter.Write(keyValue.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<string> GetAllKeys()
    {
        InitializeIndexIfNeeded();

        return _index.Keys.ToList();
    }

    public static byte[] GetData(string key)
    {
        InitializeIndexIfNeeded();

        var entry = _index[key];
        _memoryFileStream.Seek(entry.Position, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var data = new byte[entry.Length];
        _memoryFileStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

        return data;
    }

    private static void InitializeIndexIfNeeded()
    {
        if (_memoryFile != null) return;

        _memoryFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(FILE_PATH, FileMode.Open);
        _memoryFileStream = _memoryFile.CreateViewStream();

        _index = new Dictionary<string, Entry>();
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(_memoryFileStream, Encoding.Default, true))
        {
            var count = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var dataKey = binaryReader.ReadString();
                var dataPosition = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
                var dataLength = binaryReader.ReadInt32();

                _index.Add(dataKey, new Entry(dataPosition, dataLength));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It just caches the file header/index (the string keys together with the position/length of the data) in memory, the actual data is read directly from the memory mapped file only if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use Binaryformater like code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.bin";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Read_Write readWrite = new Read_Write();
            readWrite.CreateData(1000);
            readWrite.WriteData(FILENAME);
            Data data = readWrite.GetRecord(FILENAME, "101");
        }
    }
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="ABC")]
    public struct Data
    {
        public byte[] name;
        public byte[] data;
    }

    public class Read_Write
    {
        [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern int memcmp(byte[] b1, byte[] b2, long count);


        const int MIN_SIZE = 500;
        const int MAX_SIZE = 10000;
        public List<Data> data { get; set; }
        Dictionary<string, Data> dict = new Dictionary<string, Data>();


        public void CreateData(int numberRecords)
        {
            data = new List<Data>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberRecords; i++)
            {
                Data newData = new Data();

                string name = i.ToString() + '\0'; //null terminate string
                newData.name = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(name);

                Random rand = new Random();

                int size = rand.Next(MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);
                newData.data = Enumerable.Range(0, size).Select(x => (byte)(rand.Next(0, 0xFF) & 0xFF)).ToArray();

                data.Add(newData);
            }
        }
        public void WriteData(string filename)
        {
            Stream writer = File.OpenWrite(filename);
            //write number of records
            byte[] numberOfRecords = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)data.Count());
            writer.Write(numberOfRecords, 0, 4);
            foreach (Data d in data)
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(writer, d);
            }

            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
        public Data GetRecord(string filename, string name)
        {
            Data record = new Data();
            Stream reader = File.OpenRead(filename);
            byte[] numberOfRecords = new byte[4];
            reader.Read(numberOfRecords, 0, 4);
            int records = BitConverter.ToInt32(numberOfRecords, 0);

            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            for(int i = 0; i < records; i++)
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                Data d = (Data)formatter.Deserialize(reader);
                //if (name == GetString(d.name))
                //{
                //    record = d;
                //    break;
                //}

            }
            DateTime end  = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan time = end - start;

            reader.Close();
            return record;
        }

        public string GetString(byte[] characters)
        {
            int length = characters.ToList().IndexOf(0x00);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(characters, 0, length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First thanks for your quick reply, jdweng! Sure, serialization would work, but then everything would be kept in memory all the time. As the data is not needed constantly (especially not all records) I would prefer to read just the binary data (based on the string key) that I need and not just keeping everything in memory all the time. It's not that much memory considering the record size, but still it would feel wasted if only maybe 1 % of the records are needed in the whole application run.

Comment: Building the table of context the entire data would be in memory when you write the file.

Comment: Writing the file won't be done in production use as I mentioned in the question: So that's basically just a one-time task while developing the application. At production use the data is read-only (only functions "GetDataByKey" & "GetAllKeys" needed). That's why I think it would not be a very good solution to load the whole data collection into memory on every program start where just a very small percentage of the data really needs to be accessed.

Comment: The serialize had issues yesterday when I tried to serialize one Data object at a time and then deserialze one at a time.  The solution requires getting the offset of each Data object in the file.  I'm thinking of use Marshal methods rather than serialize.  If I have time I try to get it to work.  In c++ it is much easier to get it to work.

Comment: I updated code to read one record.  Did not create a table of contents.  Just read until the name matches.  I wrote number of records a first item in file.  The reads the count before reading each record.  As part of my testing I verified every deserialized record match the orignal data.

Comment: Really appreciating your time, jdweng, but if I understand your code correctly now you are not using the string key as an index, but you just iterating through EVERY single data entry in the file, deserialize all of them, till you (accidentally) find the right now. Even if only few thousands of data entries exist that sounds like a lot of overhead (and bad performance) to get a single entry.

Comment: You didn't specify performance.  And it is not accidentally.  It took .015 seconds to read the entire file.  See updated code.  There is a trade off and in some cases being perfect is not worth the effort if you are only saving tenths of a second.

Comment: Well, it's not that it would be really complex to do it right (I think the code I've posted as solution now myself is even shorter than yours), I just asked here as I thought maybe somebody else needed the same already or perhaps there is even a library for this (which I didn't find). Anyway, I've just posted a solution in case somebody else needs it in the future, too!

Comment: You are right it a 1/2 hour of time.  But it is more code to maintain.  I added code for testing which makes my code longer.